# How to handle troll comments on a question that's over 2 years old?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, specific-question, harassment

I think I'm being trolled in the [following comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484361/javascript-error-unexpected-token?noredirect=1#comment39145978_13484361):

[image: Comments]

The question is over 2 years old, solved, and he won't stop commenting and saying he's flagging me and starting to get rude. Can a moderator please wipe the comments or something? I've flagged a couple as obsolete, but now it's getting rude, calling people idiots for upvoting.

Comment: Stop engaging them, if this happens then just flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: Flag the comments or the question?

Comment: If the comments are getting out of hand, then flag the post.  I've already cleaned up a bunch of the comments.

Comment: The real winner here is Nick Dugger.

Comment: Looked like some serious sock puppeting going on, but whatevs. Gone now! =D

Comment: I still think it's hilarious. "you dont say what you have TRIED"

Comment: @J.Steen what's sock puppeting?

Comment: Seems you at least got some rep out of it [+2/-2 today already](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13484361/timeline)

Comment: @AndrewBarber indeed but at least [no one was called a tool](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267698/stackoverflow-moderators-are-tools)

Comment: @SterlingArcher http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sock-puppets tells a bit of what it is. =)

Comment: Too serious, Sterling! After TRIED, it was clear someone was throwing stones at airplanes ;)

Comment: Troll's name is ironic.

Comment: I can't stop laughing...

Comment: I'm coming back to this in two years to ask you what you have TRIED

Comment: what part of "[don't feed the troll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ulNSlES1Fds)" was not familiar?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Since the topic is removed could you tell what you have tried?

Comment: @clankill3r But then what motivation would you have to get ~9500 more rep? The SO devs have gamified your desire to see what SterlingArcher TRIED. Go forth and earn the right to see it!

Comment: @KevinStricker I don't understand a word you say. Maybe you or I should go in politics.

Comment: @clankill3r Been there, done that. You can try if you want.

Comment: I guess it's not irony, but the fact that @honk edited this question and resurrected this old question about comments on an old question is quite precious... :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Yes, it's an old question, but I think this Q&A provides valuable guidance in general. Usually, if I find a good Q&A where a post could benefit from an edit, then I try to improve it, no matter how old it is. Maybe this is my personal way of trolling ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: But I appreciate that you are paying attention. Unfortunately, not everyone notices the age of a post. I once caused a rampage on an old SO question just because I edited an old post here on Meta...

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If something like this happens, I would advise not engaging the user.  It is obvious they were trying to troll the post.  Poking/feeding/anything a troll just makes them more persistent.

If this happens in the future and they continually add useless, nonsense comments trying to start an argument, just flag the post for a moderator to review.

I've removed all the comments for the time being and handled the troll...

Comment: I love you <333

Comment: Did you use fire, or acid? EDIT: Oh; and I love you MORE!

Comment: @AndrewBarber fire and brimstone

Comment: What about the situation where you're being called a troll for no reason? I've flagged the comments but is this enough? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027164/how-to-set-border-for-my-li-element-in-my-case/26027370?noredirect=1#answer-26027370

Comment: @MelanciaUK Flag it for a moderator, it appears someone has already stepped in.  But after a flag, just ignore it.  I know it's hard, but it will keep you sane.

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, I've seen that and I just left it behind. Cheers.

Answer (score 51):

Though it was already stated here multiple times, this is the form I think is most understandable:

### Do not feed trolls

They are hungry for attention and ignoring them is the best and only remedy.

Comment: More to the point, a troll can't do much when their comment hasn't been responded to. Responding is the only way to get another troll response...

Comment: As part of the reason for not feeding: someone won't stop commenting just because you tell them to. If neither of you can bear to give the other the last word then you both have a problem. You shouldn't need the help of a moderator to ignore this.

Comment: Let's play a children's game: write to him "Hey you Troll! who says the last word is stupid". Then, whatever he writes (or not), ignore.

Comment: Or as they say don't bite the trollbait.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Yeah, but then they won't realize that they were wrong on the internet...!

Comment: Technically you can feed them a Rick(t)roll and leave. ;)

Comment: If you think these are trolls' then you have no idea what a troll is

Comment: @Rex of course not. Trolls are green creatures living under bridges, and swapping children by their own.

Comment: @Davidmh exactly, you get the point :)

Comment: @Rex and the most important thing, in this case you have to feed the little troll troll food. If you give him human food, the trolls will give your child troll food.