# I think I'm being trolled

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, abuse

A question I answered a couple of years ago suddenly got a downvote and a weird comment. I replied, and the comments just got weirder.

It has now reached the point of abuse, so I'm not going to respond any further but I wanted to raise it here because looking at his profile, it looks like he had a similar go at a couple of other questions on the same topic.

[document.all is not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880324/document-all-is-not-working-in-firefox/20884075?noredirect=1#comment68607448_20884075)

(btw, I'm aware of other questions [like this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267815/how-to-handle-troll-comments-on-a-question-thats-over-2-years-old); I'm not trying to duplicate that one - I'm not asking how to deal with it (I get it; flag it and stop engaging them); I just wanted to raise it as there seems to be some repeat behavior.

Comment: What makes you think it is repeat behavior?

Comment: Since there are no comments, i assume you flagged something and a mod already handled it.

Comment: What is the question you're asking here? How to get rid of trolls?

Answer (score 5):

You're right, the person who commented on that answer was over the line in their responses, which is why that whole conversation was purged. Someone flagged one of their comments and the rest were removed.

They are free to their vote if they disagree with your answer, but they are not free to be rude with their comments. If you see this in the future, simply flag the rude comments and moderators will deal with them. If this is a pattern with someone, rest assured we'll have a conversation with them about this.